# What does small N or small T really mean in panel data sets?

Tags: regression, panel-data, dynamic-regression

A common notion in literature on the comparison of various estimation techniques for dynamic panel models is that it's always stressed that each of these different estimation techniques perform best in different circumstances.
Especially, the differentiation between the Least-Squares Dummy Variable (LSDV) or the General Method of Moments (GMM). It is often stated that the LSDV is inconsistent for fixed $T$ and GMM is better suited for these cases. Although in cases of a small $N$ the GMM estimator suffers from a small sample bias, when $N$ is not big enough to accommodate all relevant instruments. Additionally, it is apparently often the case that the GMM estimator is not the most efficient estimator.

Since the selection of the estimation technique is crucial for the inferences one can draw from the estimation results. I would like to ask if there's a better way to determine the appropriate estimation technique and if there exists a rule of thumb for the determination of small/large $N$ or $T$.

I checked some articles comparing the different methods, like Everaert and Pozzi (2007) - Bootstrap-based bias correction for dynamic panels (http://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeedyncon/v_3a31_3ay_3a2007_3ai_3a4_3ap_3a1160-1184.htm) and Flannery, Watson Hankins (2013) - Estimating dynamic panel models in corporate finance (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092911991200096X)

Comment: Random Matrix Theory can help you understand some aspects of the N/T relationship for panel data. Basically, one can use that to estimate/filter large correlation matrix of financial time series. If $N >> T$, then you have many coefficients to estimate and only a few observations to determine them, thus lots of noise and spurious relations between the $N$ variables (since you have intuitively a larger possibility of wrongly estimate the coefficients, with many coefficients). If you have $T >> N$, then you can have precise estimates (and you decrease the prob of false coeff. with fewer coeffs).

Comment: Thanks @mic I am aware of the implications it has, if $T>>N$ or vice versa. What I find a bit puzzling is the apparent lack of clarity. I mean it's just not obvious what it means if $N$ is small 10 or 200 and the same applies to $T$. How long the time horizon should be, so that you could call it long, are ten years enough or does it have to be at least 20. Of course I am also aware there is not **one** answer to that, but it would be nice if there's some rule of thumb.

Comment: I do not know a generic one. I am afraid it is too dependent on the nature of the estimator, the quantity to be estimated, and the nature of the time series themselves and their relations. What I do is to sample from a rough model (realistic would be even better), then using bootstrapping to see what it means to be 'long' enough in this particular context (parameters for which I get stable results). I am also interested if you find a better methodology.

Comment: A somewhat related question of mine http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268273/curse-of-dimensionality-for-time-series in case you have some good ideas about it...